# Why Won't This Sugarcane Grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was recently playing on a factions server, and decided that I needed more money.  So I began building an underground sugarcane farm.  All was fine until about ten minutes later I noticed the sugarcane still hadn't grown at all.  I have the sugarcane on dirt and the room is four blocks high.  I waited even longer later and still nothing.  Why wont this sugarcane grow?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are they adjacent to water? In vanilla they do not need light but there might be mod that changes that. Other then that if you are to far away from the chunk you planted them then the chunk might not update. try staying near to your farm and see what happens.

Comment: Screenshot?  It is almost certainly a lack of water.  Water has to be adjacent to each block that you plan sugar can on.

Comment: I have water on one side of every dirt block

Comment: From your text it seem all should be well (apart from a possible mod, that is)... Can you please post a screenshot? How are things now, after couple of hours?

Comment: It does grow slightly but only one high after about 20 - 30 minutes

Comment: Strange. All seems well, and I do not recall sugar cane having a light level requirement. Try putting torches on the left maybe. Other than that, no idea :-(

Comment: i thought you had to place the sugar cane on sand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you may be dealing with an instance where the server staff has nerfed sugarcane's growth rate, most likely using a plugin, or the built-in feature of spigot.

This is often done to prevent the price of easily-farm-able goods, like sugarcane, from dropping to rock bottom, or, in the event of a server store, people getting too rich.

Ask the server staff about this, and maybe they will give you some hints for their specific implementation.

Comment: Thank You!  This seems very likely and I will ask about it soon.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why the sugarcane might not be growing:

1. The ceiling of the underground plantation is too low
2. The sugarcane needs light

   One thing you might want to try is using sand in place of the dirt, because sugarcane can grow on both. If none of these suggestions work, just try your best. :)

Comment: edits shouldn't be used to change information unless done by the author or after given permission by the author

Answer (score -5):

Wait for it to grow naturally; don't place it.